# How to change a string to a variable name

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an UNO game and I am creating the AIs right now and trying to display their random card on the screen and this is the code I have. It doesn't work as RandomImage is a string and all of the possibilities of strings outputted are defined higher up in the code. This means that whatever RandomImage equals it has been defined but it doesn't work as it is as string not a variable so how do I change RandomImage to a variable and not a string?

```
RandomImage = [str(Player1RandomColour)+str(Player1RandomNumber)]

PlayerAILabel = Label(master = window, image = RandomImage)

PlayerAILabel.place(x = 582, y = 434)
```

Comment: `RandomImage` is a list, you should create a [mcve]

Comment: You're likely looking for [eval()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval)

Comment: Probalby the best answer is to do things differently.
You could create the variables within a class and use `getattr` or just declare them in  a `dict`, where the key is the image name.

Comment: You might also want to read about PEP8 coding standard ( https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ ) , which will make it easier for others to read your code. It will then be easier to know what's a class and what's an instance.

In any case as @Sayse said `RandomImage` is a listm so probalby you hust want to write
`PlayerAILabel = Label(master = window, image =RandomImage[0]`

Comment: @LukasThaler the OP is definitly NOT "looking for `eval()`". The proper solution is do use a dict.

Comment: Use `globals()[RandomImage]` or `locals()[RandomImage]` depends on where those variables are defined.  Of course `RandomImage` must be `string` and not `list`.  However, using dict instead of those variables is better design as other said.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would have helped), what you have is something like:

```
# defined variables - value is only here for the example
Red1 = 1 
Red2 = 2
Red3 = 3
Blue1 = 11
Blue2 = 12
Blue3 = 13


# and then later you have

Player1RandomColour = "Blue"
Player1RandomNumber = "2"

varname = Player1RandomColour + Player1RandomNumber

# and what you want is to retrieve the variable named `varname`, 
# so in this case `Blue2` 

something = how_do_get_the_variable_from(varname)
assert something is Blue2
```

And the answer is, quite simply: use a `dict` innstead:

```
colors = {
    "Red1": 1, 
    "Red2": 2,
    "Red3": 3,
    "Blue1": 11,
    "Blue2": 12,
    "Blue3": 13,
}

Player1RandomColour = "Blue"
Player1RandomNumber = "2"

varname = Player1RandomColour + Player1RandomNumber
value = colors[varname]
```